# Undefined method `each ' for an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

I'm trying to iterate over an array containing various instances of a class for a test case. An array should have an `each` function according to the RubyDoc:

> Like all classes that include the Enumerable module, Array has an each method, which defines what elements should be iterated over and how.

The following code works:

```
@array = []
(0..20).to_a.each{ |i|
  @array.push(i)
}
@array.each { |i|
    puts i
}
```

But this one does not:

```
@violation_array = []
(0..2).to_a.each{ |i|
  @violation_array.push(Violation.new("violation#{i}"))
}
@violation_array.each { |violation|
  puts violation
}
```

and produces this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each ' for #<Array:0x007f3aa232ece8>
```

The value of `@violation_array.inspect` just before the `each` is:

```
[#<Violation:0x007f71e4965e30 @key="violation0">, #<Violation:0x007f71e4965bb0 @key="violation1">, #<Violation:0x007f71e49657f0 @key="violation2">]
```

Any idea on why this array lacks the `each` function?

Edit : I had this problem in multiple settings (python, ruby, markdown). 2 years later I finally understood : I always type <kbd>space</kbd> while still holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd> from a previous or following character that needs it. That makes an insecable space, see [How to disable non-breaking space with altgr+space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383074/how-to-disable-non-breaking-space-with-altgrspace) for a solution).

Comment: Your code works for me in JRuby Console [1.7.4 (1.9.3)]. But you can replace push method with <<.

Comment: I was using ruby 2.0.0p451, it seem that whitespace management changed in Ruby higher than 1.9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error message may be illuminating. There's a space in the method name so the method that doesn't exist is `"each "`. Somehow I think you've got some spurious whitespace appearing in your code. There definitely *is* an `"each"` method on arrays but not an `"each "` method.

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! It's working without the space.

Comment: Note: you should be able to use `each {` with a space between the two which makes me think there is another kind of whitespace character there.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the first example have a space before the each. I guess I somehow managed to put an insecable space after the each ? I'll really read the error message in the future.

Comment: Insecable spaces are really easy to add by mistakes before or after a special chatacter if you still hold **AltGr** while typing **space**, get rid of this problem with `setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"`