# How to disable non-breaking space with altgr+space

Tags: linux, eclipse

I keep on accidentally typing altgr+space instead of space, which results in a non-blocking space and a compiler error. I have absolutely no need to use the said character in my code other than maybe in unicode notation, so what's the best way to turn this feature of in Eclipse? Alternatively, a system wide disable for it would be fine too.

I'm running Eclipse Mars & Linux Mint 17.1 Mate

Comment: Wow, how could that space be useful?

Comment: you might want to remap the altgr+space combination. take a look here https://askubuntu.com/a/347382

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[this did the trick](http://www.hauweele.net/~gawen/blog/?p=32)

```
setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use the command xev to discover what is the keycode for AltGr on your keyboard (mine is 108). After that, you can use the xmodmap:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 108=NoSymbol'
```

I would then write this command in rc.local so I don't need to run it manually everytime I restart the machine.

Comment: Hmm, sure that it wont disable altgr completely? I scandic keyboard and braces are hidden behind altgr so I obviously need it a lot, which is also why altgr+space typos are so frequent.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was your intention. I would try something like: xmodmap -e 'keycode 65 = KP_Space KP_Space KP_Space KP_Space'. 65 is the keycode for space in my machine.

Comment: Wouldn't that touch some of the actually useful x+space combos? Like ctrl+space for autocomplete.